# Returning Key matching Value -- Adding Constraint

Tags: python, dictionary

Searching a Python dictionary based on the value first, to get a key output make sense to me. But what if we want to add another constraint to the search?

For instance, here I am searching a dictionary (multi-dimensional) for the lowest value, then returning the key of that lowest value:

```
minValue[id] = min(data[id].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Since this method only returns one key that matches that value, while there may be multiple, I want to add another constraint.

Is there an elegant way to add: return key that contains overall minimum value AND has the longest length of those matching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a specific example would be helpful to clarify what the dictionary looks like since python doesn't directly provide a multi-dimensional dict.

I assume that it looks something like this: `data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}` (note, this is not valid python!), so that what you when you do `min(data[id].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` you want it to return `('a', 1)`, and checking for the longest length matching would give, perhaps [('b', 2), ('b', 3)].

If that is what you mean, then the easiest way is to use a defaultdict with a set:

```
>>> data = defaultdict(set)
>>> data['a'].add(1)
>>> data['b'].add(2)
>>> data['b'].add(3)
>>> min(data.items(), key=lambda x: min(x[1]))
('a': {1})
>>> min(data.items(), key=lambda x: max(len(x[1])))
('b': {2, 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could add the length to the key function:

```
>>> data = {'a': 1, 'aa': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> min(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
('a', 1)
>>> min(data.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], -len(x[0])))
('aa', 1)
```

but what if there are two with the same value and the same length?  You're back to the same problem of not knowing what the output will be.  I'd probably build a list of the matching key-value pairs and then sort them or something, but the right thing to do would probably depend upon what the keys actually mean.